# UITableView left and right padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have table view. In it I have section, each section has one row only. I use the sections so that I can control the space between the rows with header height. I would like to add padding to `UITableView` so that I can space the `cells/sections` from the edges of the device. The spacing needs to have the color of the `UITableView` background.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subclass `UITableviewCell` and override `setFrame` method of it like,

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.x += inset;
    frame.size.width -= 2 * inset;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

So, it will make padding of two pixel from left and right side. you can change it as per requirement.

You can use `contentInset` but it is work only for vertical spacing (top and bottom). You should setFrame of cell as mentioned above for horizontal spacing.

You can take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317755/how-to-get-a-padding-inside-tableview) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539021/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-cell-in-a-uitableview-in-grouped-style) as a reference.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Why contentInset doesn't work for horizontal spacing?

Answer (score 10):

As Lion has been mention! His method is working fine but it's in objectiveC. Here is the method for swift 4.2

```
override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set (newFrame) {
            var frame = newFrame
            frame.origin.x += 10
            frame.size.width -= 2 * 10
            super.frame = frame
        }
    }
```

Comment: When cell in editing mode it will slide back to the wrong position. Any solution?